# Generic Methods, how to call a parent method without specifying a type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this parent class

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public static T Find<T>(string id) where T : class, new()
    {
        /* logic here ..*/
    }
}
```

and this child

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Right now, the `Find()` method can be called from child class like this `Child.Find<Child>(myId);`

What I need to change so it doesnt have to include class type like this `Child.Find(myId);`

**EDIT**

I want to make this method as extension, and get it directly without defining the class into variable. the generic class`T` should be it's child type.

Comment: Well, you can't.  You can provide a non-generic overload of Find that returns an object, but that's it.

Comment: You could just call Find<class>()

Comment: I have added the extension method solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public static Parent Find(string id)
    {
        /* logic here ..*/
    }
}
```

This way you would have to cast the output to the correct type of derived class. For example:

```
if(Parent.Find("123") is Child child)
{
   child.Name = "TEST";
}
```

**EDIT**

Hide the inherited member and define a new one:

```
    public abstract class Parent
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public static Parent Find(string id)
        {
            /* logic here ..*/
        }
    }

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public new static Child Find(string id)
        {
            /* logic here */
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to make this method as extension, and get it directly without defining the class into variable. the generic class`T` should be it's child type.

Comment: Perhaps the solution from my edit? That would let you define a completely new Find method on the child. Extension methods can't blend out existing methods

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to add this method to your `Child` class:

```
public static Child Find(string id)
{
    return Parent.Find<Child>(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public abstract class Parent<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public T Find(string id) 
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
public class Child  : Parent<Child>
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var child = base.Find ("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the extension method approach:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T Find<T>(this T source, string id) where T : class, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public void FindChild()
    {
        this.Find("");
    }
}
```